# Converting array of C strings to Swift string array

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, type-conversion, swift3

In Swift 3, C function with signature `const char *f()` is mapped to `UnsafePointer<Int8>! f()` on import. It's result can be converted to a Swift string as:

```
let swiftString = String(cString: f())
```

The question is, how a NULL terminated C array of C strings can be mapped to Swift array of strings?

The original C signature:

```
const char **f()
```

Imported Swift signature:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>! f()
```

Swift array of strings:

```
let stringArray: [String] = ???
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in method as far as I know. 
You have to iterate over the returned pointer array, converting C strings to Swift `String`s, until a `nil` pointer is found:

```
if var ptr = f() {
    var strings: [String] = []
    while let s = ptr.pointee {
        strings.append(String(cString: s))
        ptr += 1
    }
    // Now p.pointee == nil.

    print(strings)
}
```

---

*Remark:* Swift 3 uses optional pointers for pointers that can be `nil`.
In your case, `f()` returns an implicitly unwrapped optional because
the header file is not "audited": The compiler does not know whether
the function can return `NULL` or not.

Using the "nullability annotations" you can provide that information 
to the Swift compiler:

```
const char * _Nullable * _Nullable f(void);
// Imported to Swift  as
public func f() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>?
```

if the function can return `NULL`, and

```
const char * _Nullable * _Nonnull f(void);
// Imported to Swift  as
public func f() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>
```

if `f()` is guaranteed to return a non-NULL result.

For more information about the nullability annotations, see for example
[Nullability and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) in the Swift blog.

Comment: ... and very-similar techniques are needed in other languages (including C++) which support a "true" `String` type. Each of these "other" languages maintain a separate "length" for each string-value: they don't rely on terminating null-bytes. But, they all have methods which are specifically designed to deal with them. (And, commonly, they keep a known-NULL byte at the end of the current-value which they're storing.)

Comment: ... and ... *"meh" ... whenever it comes to digital computers, I "never say 'never.'" If it's a pointer, it might be `NULL`. Any future *bug* in `f()` that produced this return-value would blossom into a *very* nasty and hard-to-locate bug, wasting maybe hours from what was meant to shave microseconds. I'm a very *conservative* coder ...

Comment: @MikeRobinson: I did not add that remark to "shave microseconds" but to direct attention to the nullability annotations. Of course it can be discussed if the return value of an API which is *documented* to return a valid pointer should be checked on each invocation, or if that is considered a programming error and should crash early.

Comment: ... and, Martin, I did **not** address that comment specifically at *you.* I apologize if you interpreted it otherwise, and I can surely see how you might have.  I guess I was thinking not-so-much in terms of "nice, documented APIs," but rather, "code somewhere-else in this legacy application that we all somehow make our living to support." However, I clearly re-read that you undoubtedly *were* talking about "APIs and such." Thus, my comments may have been (in your intended context) out-of-line, and for that I do publicly apologize.

Comment: In Swift 3 I had to change `ptr += 1` to `ptr = ptr.advanced(by: 1)`

Comment: @Uncommon: Which Xcode version are you using? It still compiles for me.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 8.2.1. Maybe it's because I was working with slightly different types.

Comment: `pointee = pointee.advanced(by: strlen(addedString) + 1 )`. this moves the pointer to end-of string and adds 1 for the Null termination