# Convert a C String Array to a Swift String Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am not familiar with a way to convert a two dimensional array from C to an array of Strings which I can use in Swift. As far as I know there is no quick and easy way to do this in Swift.

**This is the header of my C function:**

```
char **getAllFilePaths(const char path []);
```

**I tried the following:**

```
//Get the pointer of the String array
if var ptr = getAllFilePaths(a) {

     //Check if the current String is null
     while let s = ptr.pointee {

        //Copy the String into an array
        a_paths.append(String(cString: s)) //<- Crash: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

        //Go to the next adress
        ptr += 1
     }

    print(a_paths)
}
```

(I have this code from Martin R: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422783/10269733. Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore in Swift 4.2)

I am searching for a solution for this problem all day, therefore I am open for any kinds of creative ideas!

EDIT:

**This code works perfectly**

```
char paths [FILES_MAX][PATH_MAX];
static size_t i = 0;

char **getAllFilePaths(const char path []){
    PrintFile(path);

    size_t j;

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%s\n", paths[j]);
    }

    return paths;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the Swift code (or related to any Swift 4.2 changes).
The real problem is that the C function returns the “2-dimensional array” variable

```
char paths[FILES_MAX][PATH_MAX];
```

as a `char **` to the caller – but that are incompatible types: one is an
array of arrays (with all characters being in contiguous memory), the other is a pointer to a pointer. There should be a compiler warning like

> incompatible pointer types returning 'char [...][...]' from a function with result type 'char **'

You *could* return `paths` from the function if you declare something like

```
typedef char PathName[PATH_MAX];

PathName *getAllFilePaths(const char path []) { ... }
```

But that would be imported to Swift as

```
typealias PathName = (Int8, Int8, ... , Int8)

public func getAllFilePaths(_ path: UnsafePointer<Int8>!) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<PathName>!
```

where `PathName` is a *tuple* of `PATH_MAX` characters – quite cumbersome
to use from Swift! Another problem is that the caller does not know
how many arrays elements have been filled.

Better define `paths` as an array of `char` pointers:

```
static char *paths[FILES_MAX] = { NULL };
```

and fill it with a NULL-terminated list of `char` pointers. Here is a
over-simplified example:

```
char **getAllFilePaths(const char path []) {
    paths[0] = "foo";
    paths[1] = "bar";
    paths[2] = NULL;
    return paths;
}
```

In your real application you do not add string *literals,* so you'll probably
have to duplicate the strings

```
    paths[j] = strdup(someString);
```

which means that at some point the strings must be `free()`d again, to avoid
memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

credits to "https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/swift-array-of-c-strings/"

C:

```
int myCFunc(char *const argv[], size_t howmany )
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < howmany; i++){
        printf("\n%s", argv[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Apart from headers/bridging:

```
// Swift:

import Foundation

public func withArrayOfCStrings<R>(
    _ args: [String],
    _ body: ([UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?]) -> R
) -> R {
    var cStrings = args.map { strdup($0) }
    cStrings.append(nil)
    defer {
        cStrings.forEach { free($0) }
    }
    return body(cStrings)
}


func goLowlevel(arguments: [String]) -> Int {

    let count = arguments.count
    return withArrayOfCStrings(arguments) {
        argv in

        myCFunc(argv, count)
        return 10
    }
}


let arr = ["AA", "BBB", "CCCC"]
goLowlevel(arguments: arr)
```